# .htaccess URL rewriting issue

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on redirecting all files in the URI(?) www.gdlsk.com/practice to this new address:
http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html

I'd all of these examples to redirect to http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html:

```
http://www.gdlsk.com/practice
http://www.gdlsk.com/practice/
http://www.gdlsk.com/practice/*
```

Where * is wildcard. Want to catch any and all requests.

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/practice
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/practice?$
#RewriteRule ^/practice http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html? [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/practice
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/practice?$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^/practice/ http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule (/practice/.*) customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html
Redirect 301 /practice http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html
Redirect 301 /practice/highform.htm http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html
Redirect 301 /practice/highform.html http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are typing query string params and you want to stop them being passed on the redirect. Add a `?` to drop the query string parameters as below

```
RewriteRule ^/practice/ http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html? [R=301,L]
```

Edit.
Based on last update this should do the trick

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/practice [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not quite. I just want to catch anybody trying to reach the form highform.htm and direct them to http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html

I'd like to catch anybody to types anything after "practice/". Just want it to be a catch-all.

Comment: Could you give me a couple of examples of urls that do not currently work and how you would like them to behave, perhaps by editing original questions - thanks

Comment: I've appended my original question. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Still nothing. It's displaying the index.html file that's in that folder. :o/

Comment: Another rule higher up likely matches before this one. Since this is very specific and should not interfere with the other rules I recommend moving it up to the top of your .htacess, just after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: That did it! Should of thought it was being overwritten by another rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using rewrites instead of redirects.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/practice/ http://www.gdlsk.com/customs-broker-regulation/customs-broker-exam-sign-up.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well that just pulls up the blank index.html. I'm using Joomla 1.5.22 I think if that matters at all.